# ASP.NET Core 3 With MySQL - Mapping Decimal

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**MySQL Database**

I have a table with the following fields

```
id  char(36) 
element_id char(36)
minimum_qualification decimal(5,2)
```

In my database, it already has values on it   ( 90.00 , 80.00, 10.00, etc...)

**ASP.NET Core 3 with Entity and MySQL**

I mapped the decimal as follows:

```
[Display(Name = "qualification")]
[Column("minimum_qualification",TypeName ="DECIMAL(5,2)")]
public decimal qualification;
```

All the other fields return just fine and the other tables using `int, timestamp` return fine. but only `decimal` `returns 0` if I use `decimal?` `returns null`  when creating a LinQ query

Im using *MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.21*

Comment: You seem to forgot `{ get; set; }` part. EF Core maps only properties, and currently `qualification` is a field.

Comment: Thank you!!  hahaha  You don't know how much I struggled